# PHP Array Data Manipulation

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of items stored in a DB and after requesting them, they are in an array (`$data`). Now there are about 200 items in the array and each of them itself is a key value array. Each element in the data array has a key called `[Acr]` and a name assigned to it.

Now the problem is that in this array

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Name Here
            [Acr] => ARR
            [Valid] => 1
            [Orig] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Name Here
            [Acr] => ABC
            [Valid] => 1
            [Orig] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Name Here
            [Acr] => XYZ
            [Valid] => 1
            [Orig] => 1
        )
    ...
```

There are items that have the same Acr but are sub elements of the first item with that Acr. So for example there are 10 more items in `$data` that have the Acr as `ARR` and I want to add those sub elements into the original (aka the first) array item with that Acr value under the key called `sub`. So after iterating it makes this.

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Name Here
            [Acr] => ABC
            [Valid] => 1
            [Orig] => 1
        )

     .....

    [14] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Name Here
            [Acr] => ARR
            [Valid] => 1
            [Orig] => 1
            [Sub] =>
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 23
                            [Name] => Sub Name Here
                            [Acr] => ARR
                            [Valid] => 1
                            [Orig] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 24
                            [Name] => Sub Name Here
                            [Acr] => ARR
                            [Valid] => 0
                            [Orig] => 1
                        )
        )

       ...
```

Now im not sure how to do this. Also, its all sorted so when you see the first `ARR` all the sub `ARR` are right under them and there are only about 5 original categories that have sub elements so if theres a way that can do this by knowing which ones to append, that would be great.

I'm not sure if I explained the problem correctly, so if you have any questions please just ask me and I will reply within minutes.

Thanks

Comment: You've explained the structure clearly enough, but what is your question? How are you hoping to manipulate or access these?

Comment: In your original array all keys are numeric. Would it be a problem, that in the manipulated array all keys are alpha-numeric?

Comment: Hi, considering that the original array is called `data` I am looking for the code that iterates through the array and makes a new array called whatever with that form where sub elements are appended the master of that key `Acr`? Does this answer your question?

Comment: @rabudde I dont think that would be a problem as long as the order of those keys remains the same.

Comment: @Kartik yes it would remain the same, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case, that alpha-numeric keys are accepted in manipulated array:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $entry) {
  if (!array_key_exists($entry['Acr'], $new)) {
    $entry['Sub'] = array();
    $new[$entry['Acr']] = $entry;
  } else $new[$entry['Acr']]['Sub'][] = $entry;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at a small function that can do this, test it and let me know if it works

```
$newRecord = array();
foreach($records as $record){
    # if the Acr already exists in a primary record,
    # insert this record as a Sub-record.
    if(array_key_exists($record['Acr'], $newRecord)){
        $newRecord[$record['Acr']]['Sub'][] = $record; 
    # else insert it as a primary record
    } else {
        $newRecord[$record['Acr']] = $record;
    }
}
```